# why arent these if statements working in this code? python restaurant selector

Tags: python-3.x

I have to make a program that asks people if they are vegetarian, vegan, or gluten free and then use that information to give a list of restauraunts that they can go to. Im having trouble with the if statements because the code will execute and you can enter yes or no to the questions but it wont print the choices of restaurants you can go to. Please help.

```
y=True
n=False

vegetarian=input("Is anyone in your party vegetarian? (y/n)")

vegan=input("Is anyone in your party vegan? (y/n)")

glutenfree=input("Is anyone in your party gluten-free? (y/n)")

print("here are your restaurant choices")

if vegetarian==False and vegan==False and glutenfree==False:
    print("Joe's Gourmet Burgers")
if vegetarian==True and vegan==False and glutenfree==True:
    print("Main Street Pizaa Company")
if vegetarian==True and vegan==True and glutenfree==True:
    print("Corner Cafe")
    print("The Chef's Kitchen")
if vegetarian==True and vegan==False and glutenfree==False:
    print("Mama's Fine Italian")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type y/n, input will return that string and not just `True` or `False`. You need to compare what the user typed to y to get a boolean value. Just to make sure you accept both upper and lower case y/n and also acidental whitespaces, strip and lower case the input.

You also don't need to compare variables to True or False, just use the variable itself or the `not` operator. The final code:

```
vegetarian=input("Is anyone in your party vegetarian? (y/n)").strip().lower()=='y'

vegan=input("Is anyone in your party vegan? (y/n)").strip().lower()=='y'

glutenfree=input("Is anyone in your party gluten-free? (y/n)").strip().lower()=='y'

print("here are your restaurant choices")

if not vegetarian and not vegan and not glutenfree:
    print("Joe's Gourmet Burgers")
if vegetarian and not vegan and glutenfree:
    print("Main Street Pizaa Company")
if vegetarian and vegan and glutenfree:
    print("Corner Cafe")
    print("The Chef's Kitchen")
if vegetarian and not vegan and not glutenfree:
    print("Mama's Fine Italian")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function returns strings:

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

The variables `vegetarian`, `vegan`, and `glutenfree` will contain either `"y"` or `"n"` strings. But you compare them to the boolean `True` and `False`, so all those conditions will fail.

A solution will be to compare them to `"y"` or `"n"`.

```
vegetarian=input("Is anyone in your party vegetarian? (y/n)")

vegan=input("Is anyone in your party vegan? (y/n)")

glutenfree=input("Is anyone in your party gluten-free? (y/n)")

print("here are your restaurant choices")

if vegetarian=="n" and vegan=="n" and glutenfree=="n":
    print("Joe's Gourmet Burgers")
if vegetarian=="y" and vegan=="n" and glutenfree=="y":
    print("Main Street Pizaa Company")
if vegetarian=="y" and vegan=="y" and glutenfree=="y":
    print("Corner Cafe")
    print("The Chef's Kitchen")
if vegetarian=="y" and vegan=="n" and glutenfree=="n":
    print("Mama's Fine Italian")
```